# localStorage : log & save, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I learn how to use localstorage and this is my code :

```
$.fn.formBackUp = function(){
    if (!localStorage) {
        return false;
    }

    var forms = this;
    var datas = {};
    datas.href = window.location.href;

    forms.find('input,textarea').keyup(function(e){
        datas[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
        localStorage.setItem('VLR_formBackUp', JSON.stringify(datas));
    });

    console.log(localStorage);

}

$('form').formBackUp();
```

i want just log and save datas , but my code is not working :/ nothing is saved

Comment: Code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/a45xq/

Answer (score 0):

The forms variable needs to be "jQuerierized" before you can use all the jQuery functions. You do that like this: `var forms = $(this);`

The final code?

```
$.fn.formBackUp = function(){
    if (!localStorage) {
        return false;
    }

    var forms = $(this);
    var datas = {};
    datas.href = window.location.href;

    forms.find('input,textarea').keyup(function(e){
        datas[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
        localStorage.setItem('VLR_formBackUp', JSON.stringify(datas));
    });

    console.log(localStorage);

}

$('form').formBackUp();
```